# Remove entrySet objects with duplicate field values

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a `Hashmap<String, List<A>>`

Currently I filter all objects from my entry list that have A.result null

```
map.entrySet().stream()
            .forEach(aList -> aList.getValue().removeIf(a -> a.result == null));
```

What I also need is to remove all A objects with duplicate result field value

so that if I have `A1.result = 1` and `A2.result = 1` I would just get one.

EDIT: Moved temporary solution as answer since no better way found yet.

Comment: What's your ouput look like?

Comment: And if `A1.result = 1` and `A2.result = 1` then what will be left in your output? A1 or A2?

Comment: Instead of List use Set, and override hashcode / equals to work it properly

Comment: @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn it wouldn't matter since all elements from the list would contain the same values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Temporary solution:

```
List<String> results= new ArrayList<>();    
map.entrySet().stream()
        .forEach(aList -> 
            aList.getValue().removeIf(a -> {
                if (a.result == null) {
                    return true;
                }
                if (results.stream().filter(result -> result.equalsIgnoreCase(a.result)).count() > 0) {
                    return true;
                }
                results.add(a.result);
                return false;
            }));
```

Answer (score 1):

As Hemant stated in [their comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50278554/remove-entryset-objects-with-duplicate-field-values#comment87574121_50278554), it would be a wise idea to override both `Object#equals` and `Object#hashCode` in `A` so two objects can be compared by their `result` field:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (!(o instanceof A)) {
        return false;
    }
    return Objects.equals(result, ((A) o).result);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(result);
}
```

Now, you can just recollect your `Map` to a `Map<String, Set<A>>`, which can be done with the following in Java 10:

```
map.entrySet()
   .stream()
   .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> Set.copyOf(e.getValue()))));
```

It's slightly different in Java 8:

```
map.entrySet()
   .stream()
   .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> new HashSet<>(e.getValue())))
```

Comment: This is only good advice if `result` is the only important field in the `A` class.

Comment: @SeanVanGorder I agree.  Another solution that I thought of is to use a `TreeSet` with a custom comparator.  If OP lets us know that they've already overridden those methods with something besides `result`, then I'll edit this answer with that solution.

Comment: @JacobG. I named the object generic A but it's a third party class actually that I cannot override without extending it.

Comment: @Fofole Does it currently override `Object#equals` or `Object#hashCode`?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe to use Set for your task? Inside forEach you can add initialisation of set and then add there your values. When you call add() method it return `false` if value is already in the set, so you'll filter it. Here is my snippet, I'm using List, but you can replace it with your A class

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashMap<String, List<Integer>> factDwhResultMap = new HashMap<>();
    factDwhResultMap.put("k1", new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,3,null)));
    factDwhResultMap.put("k2", new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(null,7,7,7,null)));

    factDwhResultMap.entrySet().stream().forEach(aList -> {
         Set resultSet = new HashSet();
         aList.getValue().removeIf(a -> a == null || !resultSet.add(a));
         System.out.println(aList);
         });
}
```

The output is

```
k1=[1, 2, 3]
k2=[7]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a very elegant one as it creates temporary objects (maps, lists)

```
actDwhResultMap.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, entry -> entry.getValue()
                .stream()
                .filter(a -> a.result != null)
                .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors
                                    .toMap(a -> a.result,
                                        java.util.function.Function.identity(),
                                        ((a1, a2) -> a1),
                                        LinkedHashMap::new),
                        result -> new ArrayList<>(result.values())))
        ));
```

It iterates through the map entries and for each value (`List<A>`) it creates a temporary map (LinkedHashMap to maintain insertion order) keyed by `A.result` and if there two objects with same `result`, it picks the first one.

At the end (in the function passed to `collectingAndThen`), it returns the values as a List. It is then inserted into a new Map keyed by the original map entry's key.

Comment: This does not remove the duplicates from the initial map, just filters them.

Answer (score 0):

Create a factory method for the predicate,

```
public static Predicate<A> nullOrDuplicate() {
    Set<Object> set = new HashSet<>();
    set.add(null);
    return a -> !set.add(a.result);
}
```

then, you can perform the operation as simple as

```
Map<String, List<A>> map;
...
map.values().forEach(list -> list.removeIf(nullOrDuplicate()));
```